# Couldn't find preset "stage-2" relative to directory

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js

I use the `presets: ['stage-2']` in the `webpack.base.config.js`:

```
 {
   test: /\.js$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   options: { presets: ['stage-2'] }
 },
```

But there gets a Error:

> Couldn't find preset "stage-2" relative to directory

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "stage-2" relative to directory "/Users/Desktop/Project/2018-02e_admin_site/src"
    at /Users/Desktop/Project/2018-02-12/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/QIYUN/Project/2018-02-12/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lisformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/Desktop/Project/2018-02-12/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/Desktop//2018-02-12/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/ormation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/Desktop/Project/2018-02-12/vue_admin_site/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transfor/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
.....
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/vendors
```

Comment: add `include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]` to resolve the src path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my Mac, I delete the `package-lock.json`, 
and then install the `babel-preset-stage-2`:

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-2 --save-dev
```

This works for me.